Are data races in assembly dangerous?
I know that a data race in C for example is undefined behaviour.
But are data races an issue at the hardware level?
If I were to write a programm in assembly where one thread writes to a certain address while another continuosly reads it using simple mov instructions, could the read cause any issues beyond reading garbage?
Is it a problem if the read and write are different sizes, but overlap?
Is it any different between x86 and ARM?
The reason I am not concerned about reading garbage is that the section in question would be guarded by a seqlock and the result of a conflicting read discarded. According to dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2247684.2247688  atomics are still necessary in C++ due to data races being UB, but I think this could be avoided in assembly.

Why would it be different in assembly?

Most architectures define the semantics of concurrent memory access somewhere.  The exact semantics differ between architectures.  There's never danger, but you can have race conditions and perhaps see torn writes and pink elephants.

@Macmade, The "C" language has a formal specification, and the specification has rules. A compliant C implementation must guarantee certain behaviors if your program conforms to the rules, but there are no guarantees if your program breaks the rules. There are rules for assembly language too, but those rules are only found in the programmer's manual for the specific processor or processor family that your program targets. So, "Why would it be different...?" It's different because you look to different authorities to find the rules.

@Ohm'sLawman Indeed, I should have clarified. For instance the C compiler is allowed to optimize away your code if it invokes undefined behavior. This won't really happen with an assembler.
I was more referring to the effects of race conditions on the software.

"could the read cause any issues beyond reading garbage?" There aren't any issues that could be categorically worse. Probably the least bad thing that could happen if your program occasionally reads a garbage value is, it crashes, and you get a reputation for writing buggy software. The worst bad thing...? If you somehow slipped a "reading garbage" bug past a world-class quality control team? Depends on what industry you work for. Trigger a global financial meltdown? A nuclear disaster? Loss of the first manned mission to Mars? etc.

@Ohm'sLawman the reason I'm fine with reading garbage is that the read will be later discarded anyway. I am looking for ways of implementing SeqLocks without using atomics for the protected data. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2247684.2247688 has some details, but I think you can get away with less atomics than that

@Ohm, of course there are many things much  worse than reading garbage. Machine check, halting the CPU, corruption of other memory locations, etc.

Here is an ARM reference (googling 'barrier litmus tests and cookbook'). https://developer.arm.com/documentation/genc007826/latest/  Each revision of a CPU will have different caveats.  I think you should move the SeqLock paper to the question.  "Dangerous" is a rather overloaded word. Also, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/wrappers/memory-barriers.html?highlight=memory+barrier  Can you state that you are a single CPU or multi-CPU, etc.

This paper is also excellent. http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/j.alglave/cats

no guarantees on either architecture with such a vague question, which generation, how many cores, mmu in play, etc.   Fully expect that there will be race conditions on either architecture with valid but stale data coming back if you follow the rules of the product, if you then get into mmu table changes without a tlb flush or write buffer flush, and a dozen other things, then you can also get garbage data, or possibly even protection faults or hangs.   and this strictly assumes ram/memory only, talking to peripherals amplifies the topic (yes seqlock so ram, just saying).

do data races happen at the hardware level: absolutely.  thus the reason for all of these features hardware and software to try to mitigate that.

ARM makes cores not chips, the majority of the memory system is non-arm chip vendor logic or IP from some other third party (ARM is a third party with respect to any arm based chip, just like all the other IP vendors products used in that chip).

@prl, I think you missed my point. Yes. You are right. There are lots of things that would be worse than merely reading garbage. But what is "garbage?" Normally, when a program "reads" a value, it did it for a reason. Normally, the program does something with that value—something that might have consequences, which could be Bad consequences if the value is "garbage." I'm thinking about the worst possible consequence if some some arbitrary "read" in some arbitrary program returns garbage.

@Ohm'sLawman: In most case, yes, of course.  But a seqlock is a special case.  We will know, after the fact, whether the value read was in fact "garbage" (not by inspecting the value itself, but from the value of the atomic sequence counter), and if so then the value will not be used for anything.  So in this particular case, there are no bad consequences from reading garbage; we just need to make sure that no other negative effects are possible.

@old_timer: I would expect that there are very few architectures which would not guarantee that a data race between a read and write will have no side effect beyond the read yielding a possibly-meaningless bit pattern, with consequent behavior that will always be consistent with some pattern of ones and zeroes having been been read, even if there was no guarantee as to what particular pattern of ones and zeroes would be read.

@old_timer: Some architectures may have regions of storage that are cached differently, and might satisfy a read request in a loose-semantics region with data that was cached before an atomic operation on a sequence counter that's stored in a tight-semantics region.  On the other hand, some algorithms may be usable in situations where writes have a certain maximum frequency (e.g. repeatedly read data until one has performed two matching reads without any interrupts having occurred between them) and no particular degree of freshness is required.

Correct, in assembly language on modern architectures, the only possible "bad" result from unsynchronized loads and stores is that you might read an "incorrect" value (i.e. the load may return a value that was never stored).
One way to think about this is that the architectural effects of a load instruction only involve writing the destination register, or faulting in case of an illegal address (protection violation, page fault, etc).  Faulting is a function only of the address and the contents of page tables, etc, and so isn't affected by concurrent access.  Thus if you don't care about the final contents of the destination register (as in the case of a seqlock) there are no other risks.
In fact, a general rule is that ordinary loads and stores of properly aligned objects of machine-word size or smaller are automatically atomic, essentially having the semantics of C++ memory_order_relaxed or better.  (On x86 they even have acquire/release semantics.)  So you're guaranteed to read a value that was actually stored, and loads and stores of the same object will observe each other in a manner consistent with program order.  For example, if thread 1 does str [x], 3 / str [x], 4 and thread 2 does ldr r0, [x] / ldr r1, [x] then it is not possible to end up with r0 == 4 && r1 == 3.  (Note that weakly ordered architectures like ARM make no such promise for accesses to different objects.)
(You probably know this, but just to make sure future readers are not misled: on x86, non-locked read-modify-write instructions like add [x], 1 perform an atomic load and an atomic store, analogous to x.store(x.load(memory_order_relaxed)+1, memory_order_relaxed), but not atomically with each other; a store from another thread could occur between the two.  To get an atomic read-modify-write, analogous to x.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed), you need lock add [x], 1.  An exception is xchg mem, reg which always has an implicit lock.)
I think that, at least on ARM and x86, overlapping accesses that are aligned, but of different sizes, are also guaranteed to behave atomically with respect to each other, "as expected".
For misaligned accesses, things are harder, and you have to refer to the fine print of the architecture spec.  AFAIK base ARMv8-A guarantees nothing except that each byte of the misaligned object is loaded/stored atomically.  ARMv8-4 with FEAT_LSE2 promises atomicity as long as you do not cross a 16-byte boundary.  x86 CPUs since P6 guarantee atomicity as long as you do not cross a cache line boundary.  Still, in all cases, the worst-case scenario is that you load a "torn" value that does not match anything that was ever stored.

This is all assuming physical addressing across threads with no mmu and/or going through the same virtual address across threads through the mmu, yes?  (non-exclusive vs exclusive transaction, and on that note aarch32 vs aarch64) And a single core processor, not multi.   The answer has too many absolutes, guaranteed, only, etc, makes it a bit scary.

also the question and answer need some restrictions since these products have been around for decades, x86 being an 8/16 bit architecture to what it is now and arm going through several architectural generations.

in the case of arm it is a core not a chip so what the chip vendor does is what the chip vendor does. and as we have seen with exclusive access in the past, arms docs are contradictory leading to variations in implementations that meet arm docs if the vendor chooses to meet arms docs (with no bugs).

the answer covers a lot of good topics in a good way but I fear it may be taken out of context as a you are guaranteed to be safe with a few rules (same address, within a limited size or ideally same size, and can somehow detect garbage (accurate but stale) data from good data).

@old_timer: Good point. My intended scope is modern x86 (say post-P6) and ARMv8-A, based on the architecture specs rather than specific implementations. I do intend to include multi-core or SMP with coherent caches.  I was thinking of "same virtual address", but I think the same rules apply to concurrent accesses to a single physical address through different virtual addresses, like with inter-process shared memory (provided of course the OS set it up properly).  Any concerns within those boundaries?  I'll edit once we've discussed it.

@old_timer: I am less familiar with other ARM architecture versions (-M, -R, pre-v7) and would be interested to see an answer about them if things are different.  Likewise for older x86 (though maybe that is Retrocomputing at this point).  But I was under the impression that the general rules "aligned loads and stores of the same size, machine-word or less, behave atomically" and "in all other cases, worst outcome is bad data" were true pretty universally across modern platforms; if there are exceptions I'd be interested to read about them.

@old_timer: (Re unaligned accesses, assuming of course that the architecture supports them at all.)  And I'm also not attempting to cover the case of memory-mapped I/O to peripherals, which of course is going to have its own rules.
